# How to use filter method for string key

Tags: javascript

I am new to this kind of problem.
I am getting an array object like this:

```js
const obj = [{
    "adId": 6,
    "receiverid": 5,
    "senderId": 7
  },
  {
    "adId": 7,
    "receiverid": 6,
    "senderId": 5
  }
]

console.log(obj.filter(item => item.adId > 5))
```

Now I want to apply filter method to apply some conditions over it.

I applied `filter()` method but the error comes that says

> filter is not a function

But I am not getting how to apply filter for this kind of object data.

Comment: May you show how you used `filter`? _"filter is not a function"_ doesn't sound right. Also update the question to include a runnable [mcve]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet to your question, with a `console.log` showing that the code is doing exactly what is expected...

Comment: Since testing your filter is working, and you mentioned you are getting the array like that, I'm guessing you are getting that content via an API call? If so, are you making sure that the string is being parsed or making sure you are getting the JSON output of the call?

Comment: Just like @imvain2 am guessing the target object mighty be an array like value but not an actual array that's why you are getting *_filter is not a function_*.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you have this object that you mentioned

```
const obj = [
    {"adId":6,"receiverid":5,"senderId":7},
    {"adId":7,"receiverid":6,"senderId":5}
];
```

If I correctly understood your question, now you want to filter only some of the object that fit according to your condition, so for that you apply filter like this

```
const filteredObjects = obj.filter((individualObject) => {
    if (individualObject['adId'] > 6) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

so now our filteredObjects will be an array like below

```
filteredObjects = [{"adId":7,"receiverid":6,"senderId":5}]
```

Comment: How’s your code different from OP’s original? It’s exactly the same. In fact yours is just more verbose.

Comment: @Terry OP question/code has been edited after I posted the solution, you can verify it by  timing, I made it more verbose for easy understanding before moving on to shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. A couple of things though. The data type is an array of objects, not an object, and your filter condition didn't filter out either object. If you change it to `item.adId > 6` it will.

```js
const arr = [{
    "adId": 6,
    "receiverid": 5,
    "senderId": 7
  },
  {
    "adId": 7,
    "receiverid": 6,
    "senderId": 5
  }
]

console.log(arr.filter(item => item.adId > 6))
```